# Unpack tuple with lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tuples

I'm trying to convert a spell checker built in Python 2 to Python 3.  I'm having trouble understanding this line.

```
outlist = sorted(as_list, key=lambda (term, (freq, dist)): (dist, -freq))
```

I've found a couple of `tuple` unpacking questions and answers, but I'm having trouble understanding what is actually happening and how to convert this particular line.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not more a feature in Python 3. Use a named function and a destructuring assignment if you want nice argument names, or something like `lambda x: (x[0][1], -x[0][0])`.